# M2: Admin grids (store config) - how to add "rowspan" to table fields?

Tags: magento2, grid, multistore, admin-panel

How can I create an admin grid that uses "rowspan" property?

We want to have (something like) the good old M1 store config page ;)

Haven't checked M1 code yet, but maybe someone has an idea ...

There is a `getRowspan()` method in

- `app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Grid/ColumnSet.php`
- `app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Grid/Extended.php`

.. but, "how to use it"?

[image]